# powerbi global object not found in typescript

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to use this power bi below code where powerbi object not found error is getting in my typescript code:

```
 // Read embed application token from textbox
var txtAccessToken = $('#txtAccessToken').val();

// Read embed URL from textbox
var txtEmbedUrl = $('#txtReportEmbed').val();

// Read report Id from textbox
var txtEmbedReportId = $('#txtEmbedReportId').val();

// Read embed type from radio
var tokenType = $('input:radio[name=tokenType]:checked').val();

// Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

// We give All permissions to demonstrate switching between View and Edit mode and saving report.
var permissions = models.Permissions.All;

// Embed configuration used to describe the what and how to embed.
// This object is used when calling powerbi.embed.
// This also includes settings and options such as filters.
// You can find more information at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details.
var config= {
    type: 'report',
    tokenType: tokenType == '0' ? models.TokenType.Aad : models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: txtAccessToken,
    embedUrl: txtEmbedUrl,
    id: txtEmbedReportId,
    permissions: permissions,
    settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: true,
        navContentPaneEnabled: true
    }
};

// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

// Embed the report and display it within the div container.
var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

// Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.
report.off("loaded");

// Report.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.
report.on("loaded", function() {
    Log.logText("Loaded");
});

report.on("error", function(event) {
    Log.log(event.detail);

    report.off("error");
});

report.off("saved");
report.on("saved", function(event) {
    Log.log(event.detail);
    if(event.detail.saveAs) {
        Log.logText('In order to interact with the new report, create a new token and load the new report');
     }
 });
```

in the above code the **powerbi** object shows not found in my typescript code: powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

I tried to use window['powerbi'] or window.powerbi but doesn't work. What should be the solution then?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue a few weeks back (probably exactly the same). For me it seems that what works is using `window.powerbi.embed()` for the embed action, whereas the import `import * as powerbi from "powerbi-client";` is used for all other Power BI objects.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, found this question through a google search.  I wasn't able to figure out why it wasn't on the window, but as a work around you can initialize it yourself like this:

```
import * as pbi from "powerbi-client";

const powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(
            pbi.factories.hpmFactory,
            pbi.factories.wpmpFactory,
            pbi.factories.routerFactory
          );
const container = document.getElementById("report-container");
powerbi.embed(container, embedConfiguration);
```